# Does systemd try to mount my luks keyfile?

Tags: systemd, automount, luks, debugging

Please help verifying if this is a bug or just misconfiguration on my part.

When I try having my LVM setup decrypted on boot, using a keyfile, the system is trying to mount the path to my keyfile, until it time-outs after 1:30 min. The same problem does, of course, not happen when I remove the path and use keyboard based authentication.

The setup: `/boot` and `/boot/efi` are unencrypted, `sda3` is LUKS-encrypted and contains all my other partitions with LVM. I have added a keyfile to sda3's LUKS and manually decrypting the partition works, of course. The error appears with the following `/etc/crypttab`:

`sda3_crypt UUID=(...) /dev/disk/by-label/BOOT:/keyfile luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev`

When booting, it's waiting on dev-disk-by-label-boot-keyfile to mount for 90 seconds. Obviously, I don't want to mount the file containing just random data.

My suspicion is that somewhere there's a parser that just looks into `/etc/crypttab` for things that look like partitions and tries to generate mount units for those paths.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that systemd-generator-crypttab will parse the file and check for devices that it could mount.

To disable this behavior alltogether, pass `luks.crypttab=no` to the kernel command line in `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`. Obviously this will disable intended behavior of that generator, too. It is, however, possible to do this in this case since it's mounting the root partition.